# Composer - Install only once?

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to have Composer only install a package once (something like a default template where the source will be changed per project)? So the package would be contained in "require" initially, but after running `composer install` the first time, it would be removed (via command line as part of a script, ideally).

I looked at `composer remove` but it seems that would delete the directory, which I don't want - I just don't want it in the `.json` or `.lock` so that if someone were to clone the repo and run `composer install` or even run `composer update` down the road, this package's directory would not be overwritten. It would become independent after first installation.

## In Practice:

- User A: `composer install`, make changes to source of Package A, which is no longer managed by composer, creates git repo that ignores Packages B-Z but tracks Package A (which isn't really a package anymore) and the changes.
- User B: 
  `git clone git@bitbucket.org:usera/repository
  cd repository
  composer install`

  Packages B-Z are installed, Package A (once again, not really a package anymore) is whatever was in the git repository.

Hopefully that's clear. Anyone have any ideas for this?

## Proposed Solutions

- Fork package each time

  - Frustrating because this would have to happen every time this composer install was used
- Fixed version number

  - Means updating the `composer.json` each time one such library is updated, not a big deal
- <strike>Replace `composer.json` after first install</strike> **Doesn't work if dirname not changed**

  - Can be done conveniently via script, but means another file in the repo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a safe approach:

1. At GitHub (yes, GitHub), fork the package that you want to make changes to a repo of your own.
2. Grab the URL of your repo and add it to your **composer.json** [`repositories`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository) information:

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "git",
           "url": "https://github.com/your-user/your-forked-repo.git"
       }
   ],
   ```
3. Require the **original package** normally. Composer will resolve to your forked version.
4. Now, you control the changes to your package. Just remember to commit from within the folder of your package. Your team members will get the updates too, push changes to GitHub and tell them to run `composer update`.

Comment: So this entire process will happen over and over again (starter theme for WP installs) so the package would have to be forked each time. This isn't really ideal.

Comment: @EthanC I guess that you should said that earlier. Check [`create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) command from Composer, it might be what you really want.

Comment: So install packages that should be updated via `composer install` and then manually (or via script) use `create-project` for anything that should be one-offed?